# Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(6\pi t)}{t}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

I have to calculate the fourier transform of this function in time domain: $\frac{\sin(6\pi t)}{t}$. First I tough to use the definition of $\operatorname{sinc}$ function as $\operatorname{sinc}(t)=\frac{\sin(2\pi t)}{t}$, but I can't get the same result of my professor: $\pi \operatorname{rect}(f/6)$. How can I get from the function to its fourier transform in this case? Just to make me understand better, I'd like to proceed in the way you proceed to calculate derivatives: you know some examples and from that you derivate everything. Thankyou!

Comment: Which convention for the Fourier transform are you using? $\int f(t) e^{-2\pi i tf}\,dt$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int f(t) e^{-itf}\,dt$, or one of the others? (Regardless, the easiest way is to compute the [inverse] FT of the rectangular function.)

Comment: I'm applying the known formulas (i.e. $rect(t)->sinc(f)$, and so on). I'd like to adapt that to my exercise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(t)=\sin(6\pi t)/t$ is square integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. So the Fourier transform is
$$
         \hat{f}(s)= \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\sin(6\pi t)}{t}e^{-ist}dt.
$$
Because $\sin(6\pi t)/t$ is even and $e^{-ist}=\cos(st)-i\sin(st)$ has odd imaginary part, then the integral for the Fourier transform reduces to a real part only. The integral of $\sin(6\pi t)\cos(st)/t$ is even in $t$; so the Fourier transform reduces to
$$
        \hat{f}(s)=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{t}\sin(6\pi t)\cos(st)dt \\
   =\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{t}\{\sin(6\pi t+st)+\sin(6\pi t-st)\}dt \\
   =\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\sin(t(6\pi+s))}{t}+\frac{\sin(t(6\pi-s))}{t}dt \\
   =\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{R(6\pi+s)}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du+\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{R(6\pi-s)}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du.
$$
The final result comes from noticing that
$$
          \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{Rv}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du = 
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du, & v > 0 \\
    0 & v = 0 \\
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{du}, & v < 0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
All you have to do is break your problem up into cases where $s < -6\pi$, $-6\pi < s < 6\pi$, $6\pi < s$. Of course you'll need to know
$$
           \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du = \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Comment: So can't I solve saying that $sinc(t)\rightarrow rect(f)$ and applying the rescaling property? Also because it's simpler even if i don't know how to do...

Comment: @lucad93 : I like this approach because you don't have to assume much of anything. There is a scaling property of $\frac{dt}{t}$ being used, where  $t=\rho s$ gives $\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{ds}{s}$, but that's fairly straightforward.